# Showing that equivalent norms in $\mathbb{R^{n}}$ implies equivalent limits?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, normed-spaces, equivalent-metrics

In a previous homework, I had to show that $$c_{2}\|x\|_{\alpha}\le\|x\|_{\beta}\le c_{1}\|x\|_{\alpha}$$
where $c_{2}, c_{1}\gt0$ and $\|\cdot\|_{\alpha}$ and $\|\cdot\|_{\beta}$ are arbitrary norms on $\mathbb{R^{n}}$. This meant that all norms were equivalent on $\mathbb{R^{n}}$.

I was wondering that if I have that $\|x_{n}\|_{\alpha}$ converges to $a$, then can I say that $\|x_{n}\|_{\beta}$ converges to $a$? I said that yes it does because $$c_{2}\|x_{n}-a\|_{\alpha}\le\|x_{n}-a\|_{\beta}\le c_{1}\|x_{n}-a\|_{\alpha}$$ where the left and right side of the inequality tend to $0$. Then, we have $$0\le\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|x_{n}-a\|_{\beta}\le0$$ So by the Squeeze Theorem, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|x_{n}-a\|_{\beta}=0$, so $\|x_{n}\|_{\beta}\rightarrow a$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yup. Why do you doubt your answer?

Comment: @copper.hat, I just wanted to make sure since a lot of my classmates were confused with this question on the previous homework and what it really meant for norms to be "equivalent" in $\mathbb{R^{n}}$. So, I was really just unsure if my thinking was correct/incorrect since my classmates were not sure either.

Comment: Trust yourself. Even when you are wrong :-).

Answer (score 0):

Only for $n=2$, to show 
$$ \|x\|_\beta\le c_2\|x\|_\gamma, x\in R^2 \tag1$$
is equivalent to show
$$ (1+z^\beta)^\frac1{\beta}\le c_2(1+z^\gamma)^\frac1{\gamma},z\in[0,\infty) $$
or
$$ (1+z^\beta)^{\gamma}\le c_2(1+z^\gamma)^{\beta}\tag2 $$
Let
$$ f(z)=\frac{(1+z^\beta)^{\gamma}}{(1+z^\gamma)^{\beta}},z\in[0,\infty). $$
It is easy to see that $f(0)=f(\infty)=1$ and hence $f(z)$ reaches the maximum $C$ in $\in[0,\infty)$. So
$$ f(z)\le C$$
and hence (2) is proved.